# HTML Reader from PHPWord does't work with tables?

Tags: php, html, phpword

When I use Html reader for my html for converting into docx, reader is cut off my table.

PHP example:

```
$reader = IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
$phpWord = $reader->load($this->getReportDir() . '/' . $fileName);
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord);
$writer->save($this->getReportDir() . '/' . $fileName);
```

Table example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>№ п/п</td>
        <td>Общие показатели результатов прохождения проверочных листов</td>
        <td>Количество пройденных проверок</td>
        <td>% от общего количества пройденных проверок</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 8):

The current HTML class from PHPWord is very limited. The issue you are getting is a know issue (see https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/324).

I'm working on a project that needs some HTML tables to doc conversion. So, I work a little improving the HTML class. It is very little tested and I just tested DOC conversion.

My version is able to convert the following HTML:

```
<table style="width: 50%; border: 6px #0000FF solid;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #FF0000; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; ">
             <th>a</th>
             <th>b</th>
             <th>c</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td colspan="2">2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Generating the following DOC table:

[image]

It uses PHPWord version 0.13:

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is part of PHPWord - A pure PHP library for reading and writing
 * word processing documents.
 *
 * PHPWord is free software distributed under the terms of the GNU Lesser
 * General Public License version 3 as published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code. For the full list of
 * contributors, visit https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/contributors.
 *
 * @link        https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord
 * @copyright   2010-2016 PHPWord contributors
 * @license     http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.txt LGPL version 3
 */

namespace PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared;

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Row;

/**
 * Common Html functions
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedPrivateMethod) For readWPNode
 */
class Html
{
    //public static $phpWord=null;

    /**
    *  Hold styles from parent elements,
    *  allowing child elements inherit attributes.
    *  So if you whant your table row have bold font
    *  you can do:
    *     <tr style="font-weight: bold; ">
    *  instead of
    *     <tr>
    *       <td>
    *           <p style="font-weight: bold;">
    *       ...
    *
    *  Before DOM element children are processed,
    *  the parent DOM element styles are added to the stack.
    *  The styles for each child element is composed by
    *  its styles plus the parent styles.
    */
    public static $stylesStack=null;

    /**
     * Add HTML parts.
     *
     * Note: $stylesheet parameter is removed to avoid PHPMD error for unused parameter
     *
     * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element Where the parts need to be added
     * @param string $html The code to parse
     * @param bool $fullHTML If it's a full HTML, no need to add 'body' tag
     * @return void
     */
    public static function addHtml($element, $html, $fullHTML = false)
    {
        /*
         * @todo parse $stylesheet for default styles.  Should result in an array based on id, class and element,
         * which could be applied when such an element occurs in the parseNode function.
         */

        // Preprocess: remove all line ends, decode HTML entity,
        // fix ampersand and angle brackets and add body tag for HTML fragments
        $html = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $html);
        $html = str_replace(array('&lt;', '&gt;', '&amp;'), array('_lt_', '_gt_', '_amp_'), $html);
        $html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $html = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $html);
        $html = str_replace(array('_lt_', '_gt_', '_amp_'), array('&lt;', '&gt;', '&amp;'), $html);

        if (false === $fullHTML) {
            $html = '<body>' . $html . '</body>';
        }

        // Load DOM
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
        $dom->loadXML($html);
        $node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');

        //self::$phpWord = $element->getPhpWord();
        self::$stylesStack = array();

        self::parseNode($node->item(0), $element);
    }

    /**
     * parse Inline style of a node
     *
     * @param \DOMNode $node Node to check on attributes and to compile a style array
     * @param array $styles is supplied, the inline style attributes are added to the already existing style
     * @return array
     */
    protected static function parseInlineStyle($node, $styles = array())
    {
        if (XML_ELEMENT_NODE == $node->nodeType) {
            $stylesStr = $node->getAttribute('style');
            $styles = self::parseStyle($node, $stylesStr, $styles);
        }
        else
        {
            // Just to balance the stack.
            // (make number of pushs = number of pops)
            self::pushStyles(array());
        } 

        return $styles;
    }

    /**
     * Parse a node and add a corresponding element to the parent element.
     *
     * @param \DOMNode $node node to parse
     * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element object to add an element corresponding with the node
     * @param array $styles Array with all styles
     * @param array $data Array to transport data to a next level in the DOM tree, for example level of listitems
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function parseNode($node, $element, $styles = array(), $data = array())
    {
        // Populate styles array
        $styleTypes = array('font', 'paragraph', 'list', 'table', 'row', 'cell'); //@change
        foreach ($styleTypes as $styleType) {
            if (!isset($styles[$styleType])) {
                $styles[$styleType] = array();
            }
        }

        // Node mapping table
        $nodes = array(
                              // $method        $node   $element    $styles     $data   $argument1      $argument2
            'p'         => array('Paragraph',   $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   null,           null),
            'h1'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading1',     null),
            'h2'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading2',     null),
            'h3'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading3',     null),
            'h4'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading4',     null),
            'h5'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading5',     null),
            'h6'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading6',     null),
            '#text'     => array('Text',        $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   null,           null),
            'strong'    => array('Property',    null,   null,       $styles,    null,   'bold',         true),
            'em'        => array('Property',    null,   null,       $styles,    null,   'italic',       true),
            'sup'       => array('Property',    null,   null,       $styles,    null,   'superScript',  true),
            'sub'       => array('Property',    null,   null,       $styles,    null,   'subScript',    true),
            // @change
            //'table'     => array('Table',       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   'addTable',     true),
            //'tr'        => array('Table',       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   'addRow',       true),
            //'td'        => array('Table',       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   'addCell',      true),
            'table'     => array('Table' ,       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   null,     true),
            'tr'        => array('Row'   ,       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   null,       true),
            'td'        => array('Cell'  ,       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   null,      true),
            'th'        => array('Cell'  ,       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   null,      true),
            'ul'        => array('List',        null,   null,       $styles,    $data,  3,              null),
            'ol'        => array('List',        null,   null,       $styles,    $data,  7,              null),
            'li'        => array('ListItem',    $node,  $element,   $styles,    $data,  null,           null),
        );

        $newElement = null;
        $keys = array('node', 'element', 'styles', 'data', 'argument1', 'argument2');

        if (isset($nodes[$node->nodeName])) {
            // Execute method based on node mapping table and return $newElement or null
            // Arguments are passed by reference
            $arguments = array();
            $args = array();
            list($method, $args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3], $args[4], $args[5]) = $nodes[$node->nodeName];
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
                if ($args[$i] !== null) {
                    $arguments[$keys[$i]] = &$args[$i];
                }
            }
            $method = "parse{$method}";
            $newElement = call_user_func_array(array('PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html', $method), $arguments);

            // Retrieve back variables from arguments
            foreach ($keys as $key) {
                if (array_key_exists($key, $arguments)) {
                    $$key = $arguments[$key];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Just to balance the stack.
            // Number of pushs = number of pops.
            self::pushStyles(array());
        }

        if ($newElement === null) {
            $newElement = $element;
        }

        self::parseChildNodes($node, $newElement, $styles, $data);

        // After the parent element be processed, 
        // its styles are removed from stack.
        self::popStyles();
    }

    /**
     * Parse child nodes.
     *
     * @param \DOMNode $node
     * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element
     * @param array $styles
     * @param array $data
     * @return void
     */
    private static function parseChildNodes($node, $element, $styles, $data)
    {
        if ('li' != $node->nodeName) {
            $cNodes = $node->childNodes;
            if (count($cNodes) > 0) {
                foreach ($cNodes as $cNode) {
                    if (($element instanceof AbstractContainer) or ($element instanceof Table) or ($element instanceof Row)) { // @change
                        self::parseNode($cNode, $element, $styles, $data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse paragraph node
     *
     * @param \DOMNode $node
     * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element
     * @param array &$styles
     * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextRun
     */
    private static function parseParagraph($node, $element, &$styles)
    {
        $elementStyles = self::parseInlineStyle($node, $styles['paragraph']);

        $newElement = $element->addTextRun($elementStyles);

        return $newElement;
    }

    /**
     * Parse heading node
     *
     * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element
     * @param array &$styles
     * @param string $argument1 Name of heading style
     * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextRun
     *
     * @todo Think of a clever way of defining header styles, now it is only based on the assumption, that
     * Heading1 - Heading6 are already defined somewhere
     */
    private static function parseHeading($element, &$styles, $argument1)
    {
        $elementStyles = $argument1;

        $newElement = $element->addTextRun($elementStyles);

        return $newElement;
    }

    /**
     * Parse text node
     *
     * @param \DOMNode $node
     * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element
     * @param array &$styles
     * @return null
     */
    private static function parseText($node, $element, &$styles)
    {
        $elementStyles = self::parseInlineStyle($node, $styles['font']);

        $textStyles = self::getInheritedTextStyles();
        $paragraphStyles = self::getInheritedParagraphStyles();

        // Commented as source of bug #257. `method_exists` doesn't seems to work properly in this case.
        // @todo Find better error checking for this one
        // if (method_exists($element, 'addText')) {
            $element->addText($node->nodeValue, $textStyles, $paragraphStyles);
        // }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Parse property node
     *
     * @param array &$styles
     * @param string $argument1 Style name
     * @param string $argument2 Style value
     * @return null
     */
    private static function parseProperty(&$styles, $argument1, $argument2)
    {
        $styles['font'][$argument1] = $argument2;

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Parse table node
     *
     * @param \DOMNode $node
     * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element
     * @param array &$styles
     * @param string $argument1 Method name
     * @return \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element
     *
     * @todo As soon as TableItem, RowItem and CellItem support relative width and height
     */
    private static function parseTable($node, $element, &$styles, $argument1)
    {
        $elementStyles = self::parseInlineStyle($node, $styles['table']);

        $newElement = $element->addTable($elementStyles);

        // $attributes = $node->attributes;
        // if ($attributes->getNamedItem('width') !== null) {
            // $newElement->setWidth($attributes->getNamedItem('width')->value);
        // }

        // if ($attributes->getNamedItem('height') !== null) {
            // $newElement->setHeight($attributes->getNamedItem('height')->value);
        // }
        // if ($attributes->getNamedItem('width') !== null) {
            // $newElement=$element->addCell($width=$attributes->getNamedItem('width')->value);
        // }

        return $newElement;
    }

    private static function parseRow($node, $element, &$styles, $argument1)
    {
        $elementStyles = self::parseInlineStyle($node, $styles['row']);

        $newElement = $element->addRow(null, $elementStyles);

        return $newElement;
    }


    private static function parseCell($node, $element, &$styles, $argument1)
    {        
        $elementStyles = self::parseInlineStyle($node, $styles['cell']);

        $colspan = $node->getAttribute('colspan');        
        if (!empty($colspan))
            $elementStyles['gridSpan'] = $colspan-0;        

        $newElement = $element->addCell(null, $elementStyles);
        return $newElement;
    }

    /**
     * Parse list node
     *
     * @param array &$styles
     * @param array &$data
     * @param string $argument1 List type
     * @return null
     */
    private static function parseList(&$styles, &$data, $argument1)
    {
        if (isset($data['listdepth'])) {
            $data['listdepth']++;
        } else {
            $data['listdepth'] = 0;
        }
        $styles['list']['listType'] = $argument1;

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Parse list item node
     *
     * @param \DOMNode $node
     * @param \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\AbstractContainer $element
     * @param array &$styles
     * @param array $data
     * @return null
     *
     * @todo This function is almost the same like `parseChildNodes`. Merged?
     * @todo As soon as ListItem inherits from AbstractContainer or TextRun delete parsing part of childNodes
     */
    private static function parseListItem($node, $element, &$styles, $data)
    {
        $cNodes = $node->childNodes;
        if (count($cNodes) > 0) {
            $text = '';
            foreach ($cNodes as $cNode) {
                if ($cNode->nodeName == '#text') {
                    $text = $cNode->nodeValue;
                }
            }
            $element->addListItem($text, $data['listdepth'], $styles['font'], $styles['list'], $styles['paragraph']);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Parse style
     *
     * @param \DOMAttr $attribute
     * @param array $styles
     * @return array
     */
    private static function parseStyle($node, $stylesStr, $styles)
    {
        // Parses element styles.
        $newStyles = array();

        if (!empty($stylesStr))
        {
            $properties = explode(';', trim($stylesStr, " \t\n\r\0\x0B;"));
            foreach ($properties as $property) {
                list($cKey, $cValue) = explode(':', $property, 2);
                $cValue = trim($cValue);
                switch (trim($cKey)) {
                    case 'text-decoration':
                        switch ($cValue) {
                            case 'underline':
                                $newStyles['underline'] = 'single';
                                break;
                            case 'line-through':
                                $newStyles['strikethrough'] = true;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;                
                    case 'text-align':
                        $newStyles['alignment'] = $cValue; // todo: any mapping?
                        break;
                    case 'color':
                        $newStyles['color'] = trim($cValue, "#");
                        break;
                    case 'background-color':
                        $newStyles['bgColor'] = trim($cValue, "#");
                        break;

                    // @change
                    case 'colspan':
                        $newStyles['gridSpan'] = $cValue-0;
                        break;
                    case 'font-weight':
                        if ($cValue=='bold')
                            $newStyles['bold'] = true;
                        break;                    
                    case 'width':
                        $newStyles = self::parseWidth($newStyles, $cValue);
                        break;
                    case 'border-width':
                        $newStyles = self::parseBorderStyle($newStyles, $cValue);
                        break;
                    case 'border-color':
                        $newStyles = self::parseBorderColor($newStyles, $cValue);
                        break;
                    case 'border':
                        $newStyles = self::parseBorder($newStyles, $cValue);
                        break;                    
                }
            }
        }

        // Add styles to stack.
        self::pushStyles($newStyles);

        // Inherit parent styles (including itself).
        $inheritedStyles = self::getInheritedStyles($node->nodeName);

        // Override default styles with the inherited ones.
        $styles = array_merge($styles, $inheritedStyles);       

        /* DEBUG
        if ($node->nodeName=='th')
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r(self::$stylesStack);
            print_r($styles);
            //print_r($elementStyles);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
        */

        return $styles;
    }

    /**
    *  Parses the "width" style attribute, adding to styles
    *  array the corresponding PHPWORD attributes.
    */
    public static function parseWidth($styles, $cValue)
    {
        if (preg_match('/([0-9]+)px/', $cValue, $matches))
        {
            $styles['width'] = $matches[1];
            $styles['unit'] = 'dxa';
        }
        else if (preg_match('/([0-9]+)%/', $cValue, $matches))
        {
            $styles['width'] = $matches[1]*50;
            $styles['unit'] = 'pct';
        }
        else if (preg_match('/([0-9]+)/', $cValue, $matches))
        {
            $styles['width'] = $matches[1];
            $styles['unit'] = 'auto';
        }

        $styles['alignment'] = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\JcTable::START;

        return $styles;
    }

    /**
    *  Parses the "border-width" style attribute, adding to styles
    *  array the corresponding PHPWORD attributes.
    */
    public static function parseBorderWidth($styles, $cValue)
    {
        // border-width: 2px;
        if (preg_match('/([0-9]+)px/', $cValue, $matches))
            $styles['borderSize'] = $matches[1];

        return $styles;
    }

    /**
    *  Parses the "border-color" style attribute, adding to styles
    *  array the corresponding PHPWORD attributes.
    */
    public static function parseBorderColor($styles, $cValue)
    {
        // border-color: #FFAACC;
        $styles['borderColor'] = $cValue;

        return $styles;
    }    

    /**
    *  Parses the "border" style attribute, adding to styles
    *  array the corresponding PHPWORD attributes.
    */
    public static function parseBorder($styles, $cValue)
    {
        if (preg_match('/([0-9]+)px\s+(\#[a-fA-F0-9]+)\s+solid+/', $cValue, $matches))
        {
            $styles['borderSize'] = $matches[1];
            $styles['borderColor'] = $matches[2];
        }

        return $styles;
    }

    /**
    *  Return the inherited styles for text elements,
    *  considering current stack state.
    */
    public static function getInheritedTextStyles()
    {
        return self::getInheritedStyles('#text');
    }

    /**
    *  Return the inherited styles for paragraph elements,
    *  considering current stack state.
    */
    public static function getInheritedParagraphStyles()
    {
        return self::getInheritedStyles('p');
    }

    /**
    *  Return the inherited styles for a given nodeType,
    *  considering current stack state.
    */
    public static function  getInheritedStyles($nodeType)
    {
        $textStyles = array('color', 'bold', 'italic');
        $paragraphStyles = array('color', 'bold', 'italic', 'alignment');

        // List of phpword styles relevant for each element types.
        $stylesMapping = array(
            'p'         => $paragraphStyles,
            'h1'        => $textStyles,
            'h2'        => $textStyles,
            'h3'        => $textStyles,
            'h4'        => $textStyles,
            'h5'        => $textStyles,
            'h6'        => $textStyles,
            '#text'     => $textStyles,
            'strong'    => $textStyles,
            'em'        => $textStyles,
            'sup'       => $textStyles,
            'sub'       => $textStyles,
            'table'     => array('width', 'borderSize', 'borderColor', 'unit'),
            'tr'        => array('bgColor', 'alignment'),
            'td'        => array('bgColor', 'alignment'),
            'th'        => array('bgColor', 'alignment'),
            'ul'        => $textStyles,
            'ol'        => $textStyles,
            'li'        => $textStyles,
        );

        $result = array();

        if (isset($stylesMapping[$nodeType]))
        {
            $nodeStyles = $stylesMapping[$nodeType];

            // Loop trough styles stack applying styles in
            // the right order.
            foreach (self::$stylesStack as $styles)
            {
                // Loop trough all styles applying only the relevants for
                // that node type.
                foreach ($styles as $name => $value)
                {
                    if (in_array($name, $nodeStyles))
                    {
                        $result[$name] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }


    /**
    *  Add the parent styles to stack, allowing
    *  children elements inherit from.
    */
    public static function pushStyles($styles)
    {
        self::$stylesStack[] = $styles;
    }

    /**
    *  Remove parent styles at end of recursion.
    */
    public static function popStyles()
    {
        array_pop(self::$stylesStack);
    }
}
```

With this new structure it is easy add new style support. You just need edit the parseStyle() method and the $stylesMapping variable (at getInheritedStyles() method). Hope it helps.

Example of use:

```
<?php
include_once 'Sample_Header.php';

// New Word Document
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Create new PhpWord object' , EOL;
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$html  = '<table style="width: 50%; border: 6px #0000FF solid;">'.
            '<thead>'.
                '<tr style="background-color: #FF0000; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; ">'.
                    '<th>a</th>'.
                    '<th>b</th>'.
                    '<th>c</th>'.
                '</tr>'.
            '</thead>'.
            '<tbody>'.
                '<tr><td>1</td><td colspan="2">2</td></tr>'.
                '<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>'.
            '</tbody>'.
         '</table>';


\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html);

// Save file
echo write($phpWord, basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $writers);
if (!CLI) {
    include_once 'Sample_Footer.php';
}
```

Comment: (there is only a little mistake in the above code:
" $newStyles = self::parseBorderStyle($newStyles, $cValue); " 
should be changed to: 
" $newStyles = self::parseBorderWidth($newStyles, $cValue); "

Comment: Hello, Arivan! You're great! Have you finished this project? If yes, could you please provide the full Hmtl.php file for me, as I have the same task?)

Comment: I'm sorry @SergejFomin but the last source code I have is this one.

Comment: thanx, anyway, Arivan Bastos:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `thead` and `tbody` tags, like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>№ п/п</th>
      <th>Общие показатели результатов прохождения проверочных листов</th>
      <th>Количество пройденных проверок</th>
      <th>% от общего количества пройденных проверок</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a comment of this Aviran Post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40600565/6635967 (I don't have enought reputation to comment).

I tried his method and I had this error :

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "addText" of class "PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table".
```

To fix this, I had to modified the parseText function like this :

```
    private static function parseText($node, $element, &$styles)
{
    $elementStyles = self::parseInlineStyle($node, $styles['font']);

    $textStyles = self::getInheritedTextStyles();
    $paragraphStyles = self::getInheritedParagraphStyles();

    // Commented as source of bug #257. `method_exists` doesn't seems to work properly in this case.
    // @todo Find better error checking for this one
    if (method_exists($element, 'addText')  || $element instanceof Cell ) {
        $element->addText($node->nodeValue, $textStyles, $paragraphStyles);
    }

    return null;
}
```

It's not a good bug fix but it's works very well for me.

Comment: This works - but no text is appearing now. Only for list items it seems. Paragraphs and headings are all blank.

Comment: Did you ckeck textStyles ?

Comment: Please explain...the docs on usage for this is very thin. Am I supposed to define them?

Comment: You don't need  to define them. I didn't have this bug, if you find the answer, I'm curious to know it.