# Create Table without borders, td with only border bottom using phpword & html to docx converter

Tags: php, html, css, phpword

I'm trying so hard to create a table without borders and give a td only border bottom with no joy. I'm using the html to docx convert in conjunction with phpword. I've tried inline styles or using the "style.inc" file but no luck:

Style.inc

```
"table" => array(
                        // Note that applying a table style in PHPWord applies the relevant style to
                        // ALL the cells in the table. So, for example, the borderSize applied here
                        // applies to all the cells, and not just to the outer edges of the table:
                        "size" => 11,
                        "border" => 0,
                        "width" => "100%",
                        "borderSize" => 0,
                        "lineHeight" => 20,
                    )
```

HTML:

```
                $html .= '<table border="0" style="border: 0 none;">';
                $html .= '  <tr>';
                $html .= '      <td colspan="4"><h2>Header 1</h2></td>';
                $html .= '  </tr>';
                $html .= '  <tr>';
                $html .= '      <th style="border: 0 none; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;"><b>Site Address</b></th>';
                $html .= '      <th style="border: 0 none; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;"><b>No. of Units</b></th>';
                $html .= '      <th style="border: 0 none; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;"><b>Value</b></th>';
                $html .= '      <th style="border: 0 none; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;"><b>Size in m<sup>2</sup></b></th>';
                $html .= '  </tr>';
                $html .= '  <tr>';
                $html .= '      <td style="vertical-align: middle" width="300">Sample Text</td>';
                $html .= '      <td style="vertical-align: middle" width="300">Sample Text</td>';
                $html .= '      <td style="vertical-align: middle" width="300">Sample Text</th>';
                $html .= '      <td style="vertical-align: middle" width="300">Sample Text</td>';
                $html .= '  </tr>';
                $html .= '  <tr>';
                $html .= '      <td colspan="4"><h2>Professional Contact Details:</h2></td>';
                $html .= '  </tr>';
                $html .= '  <tr>';
                $html .= '      <th width="300"><b>Company</b></th>';
                $html .= '      <th width="300"><b>Address</b></th>';
                $html .= '      <th width="300"><b>Contact Person</b></th>';
                $html .= '      <th width="300"><b>Contact</b></th>';
                $html .= '  </tr>';
                $html .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Which version of the PhpWord are you using? Probably some older version because you don't need a separate html to docx converter for the new versions... at least in the new version this is easy to achieve if you don't need to define the table structure as html (i.e. if you can use the phpword table elements instead)

Comment: The current HTML class from PHPWord is very limited. I work a little improving it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275140/html-reader-from-phpword-doest-work-with-tables/40600565#40600565. You can easily add border styles editing parseStyle method.