# HTML to DOCX file with php

Tags: php

code in index.php

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents( $_REQUEST['fname']);
$filename = 'form_' . uniqid () . '.doc';
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= . $filename");
echo $html;

?>
```

Path of html file

```
form_588f71c4e978d.html
```

after running

```
http://localhost/html2/html2wordf.php?fname=form_588f71c4e978d.html
```

i m getting below code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

inside

```
form_588f71c4e978d.doc
```

but i want only `hello` 
inside this file

means html to doc data conversion is not working , it just changing its extension from .html to .doc and data inside both the file remain same

any one getting my point ? Guide me   thanks

Comment: Who told you this *snippet* would convert HTML to a proper Word file? It merely sends a fake Content-Type. (Unless there is other code you haven't shown.)

Comment: *means html to doc data conversion is not working* of course ... there is no conversion called

Comment: HTML markup in a file is neither `doc`, nor `docx`; it's simply html markup in a file with a different extension

Comment: Simply setting a header does not magically make it a word file

Comment: Consider looking at a library like [PHPOffice/PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) that can convert html markup to a real BIFF (`doc`) or OfficeOpenXML (`docx`) format file

Comment: then what should i do ?

Comment: means need to add a library ?

Comment: See also: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+convert+html+to+docs

Comment: thanks All..........................   :)

Answer (score 3):

There is good PHP library, but it's non free:
http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/introduction/html-to-word-PHP

If you just want replace some text in your word template (I suggest that you use docx format) **you can  unzip docx file and you will find XML file this content.**

So, you can use str_replace('{{youVariableInWordTemplate}}', $value, $wordXML);

**Another way: use PhpWord**

```
$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$html = '<p><strong>You html here</strong></p>';
Html::addHtml($section, $html);

$objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$cacheDir = '/temp_directory_of_your_project/';
$objWriter->save($cacheDir. 'helloWorld.docx');
```

But this library has problem with table generating. There is opened issue: [Using table tag in HTML Reader produces no output](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/324#issuecomment-180492160) with solution to use custom class (see attachment in the post)

Also you can find improved implementation: [HTML Reader from PHPWord does't work with tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275140/html-reader-from-phpword-doest-work-with-tables/40600565#40600565)

This library support not many HTML tags (array with supported tags below):

```
$nodes = array(
        // $method        $node   $element    $styles     $data   $argument1      $argument2
        'p'         => array('Paragraph',   $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   null,           null),
        'h1'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading1',     null),
        'h2'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading2',     null),
        'h3'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading3',     null),
        'h4'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading4',     null),
        'h5'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading5',     null),
        'h6'        => array('Heading',     null,   $element,   $styles,    null,   'Heading6',     null),
        '#text'     => array('Text',        $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,    null,          null),
        'span'      => array('Span',        $node,  null,       $styles,    null,    null,          null), //to catch inline span style changes
        'strong'    => array('Property',    null,   null,       $styles,    null,   'bold',         true),
        'em'        => array('Property',    null,   null,       $styles,    null,   'italic',       true),
        'sup'       => array('Property',    null,   null,       $styles,    null,   'superScript',  true),
        'sub'       => array('Property',    null,   null,       $styles,    null,   'subScript',    true),
        'table'     => array('Table',       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   'addTable',     true),
        'tbody'     => array('Table',       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   'skipTbody',    true), //added to catch tbody in html.
        'tr'        => array('Table',       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   'addRow',       true),
        'td'        => array('Table',       $node,  $element,   $styles,    null,   'addCell',      true),
        'ul'        => array('List',        null,   null,       $styles,    $data,  3,              null),
        'ol'        => array('List',        null,   null,       $styles,    $data,  7,              null),
        'li'        => array('ListItem',    $node,  $element,   $styles,    $data,  null,           null),
    );
```

Comment: And what about inined styles this biblio does not work even !