# How can i convert html file to docx in PHP without any library?

Tags: php, html, doc

I tried to use header then generate a new file like this

```
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment; Filename=file_name.docx");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: file_size");
    echo $_POST['html'];
```

But it didn't work,
Can I convert `HTML file` to `docx` without using any library?

Comment: _"without any library"_ - You need to do a lot of research into how the docx-format works and then output your code correctly. The question is way too broad as it is. Just adding headers to your HTML output doesn't make it a proper docx. It will just be html which you told your browser to use as docx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML to DOCX file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024657/html-to-docx-file-with-php)

Comment: @MrSimple - How would that dupe answer their question? The only answer are all talking about using libraries, or replace some word in an existing word template. The OP here specifically says "without any library"

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are right, I misread the answer, I'm sorry.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you, I already did a "lot of research" to try that but I really need to try that without using any library, because I need an alternative solution, anyway I tried `PHPWord` and it worked.

Comment: What I meant was that you need to study the docx _format_ in detail. You need to know how it works inside out if you want to create valid docx files without a library. That is way too broad of a question for this site though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok, I'll try to use another library instead of `PHPWord`, which library do you prefer?

Answer (score -2):

Just put this below code in the top of the page need to convert:

```js
<?php
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=Report.doc");
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't turn the result into a docx. That's just you telling the browser to treat the output like it, which won't work if the output isn't a valid docx-file

Comment: Put it at top of your html doc and it will given you doc file for that html file once run page .  <?php  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=Report.doc");
?>  you can add condition  for on  button click etc to run this on some event submit  not every time

Comment: @VikasGautam - As mentioned, that will _not_ give you a proper docx-file. That will just give you a HTML-file with a .doc-extension. Those headers doesn't _change_ the format of the file, it just tells the browser to _treat_ the file as a Word document. Since Word can read HTML files, it will be able to read it. However, it's still not a real Word document (which can contain much more than a HTML file can, like macros etc)

Comment: Hello @MagnusEriksson thanks for clarifying this thing but I want to know that what we should modify in my response so we can get exact docx, thanks

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to the original question, that would be _way_ too broad for this site. docx is not a trivial format so there is no quick or easy modification to make the above produce proper docx-files.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so do you mean that for proper docx we would need to integrate the third-party library

Comment: The OP said "no library". Doing it without a library, you would need to study the format and build the document from that (a lot of work). if you're OK with using a third party library, then I would def. recommend that. So you either do a lot of work to create it yourself or you use a library made by people that already done the research and the work.